# How to de-duplicate SQL records to keep the last entry

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table called "messages" with:

```
id, owner, content
"id1", "bob", "c1"
"id1", "alice", "c2"
"id2", "bob", "c3"
"id3", "charles", "c4"
```

The messages represent a sequence of in-order events. If there are two events with the same id, then only the last one should be shown.

(By "last" I mean from top to bottom, I don't know if I can use the rowid to order this or if I would need an auto incrementing integer)

I want to retrieve id,owner,content but only receive distinct ids:

```
"id1","alice","c2"
"id2","bob","c3"
"id3","charles","c4"
```

How can I query for this with sqlite?

Comment: Which is "the last one"? That one having the maximum content? Please be more precise.

Comment: There is no "last" in a table unless you define how to order your data; I see no reliable ordering column in your sample data.

Comment: By "last" I mean from top to bottom, I don't know if I can use the rowid to order this or if I would need an auto incrementing integer

Comment: Is your data always be "sorted" this way, meaning the entry with the highest content per id will appear as "last"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function while casting `content` column to an integer value such as

```
WITH t1 AS
(   
 SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(content,'c','') AS INT) DESC) AS rn
   FROM t
)
SELECT id, owner, content
  FROM t1
 WHERE rn = 1
```

presuming the order is based on the numeric value of that column which  only has `c` prefixed values for those integers.